# Apex coding for a newbie

Tags: help, learning

Not sure if this is the right place but thought I'd ask the question. I have no coding experience whatsoever and looking to get involved in this as this is something that interests me greatly. Can anyone recommend a good website/book to learn the basics firstly?

Comment: Trailhead Administrator and CRM basics paths should get u more familiar. Welcome and good luck.

Answer (score 6):

Your site-number-one is:

https://developer.salesforce.com/

Over there take a look at the LIBRARY:

- The official SFDC [Documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs) helps you to lear all about Force.com programming language **APEX** and **Visualforce**, Database query languages (**SOQL** and **SOSL**) and lots of **API**
- [Developer Resources](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Wiki) will give you an overview in **code snippets and tutorials**
- If you wish to dive deeper in that topics just go to the [Force.com Books](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Force.com_Books) and learn more about Force.com platform

On the [Tools](http://developer.salesforce.com/page/Tools) page you will find an overview of the Force.com programming tool and helpful topics.

Comment: We always start our new devs off with the Force.com Workbook. I did it myself and found it invaluable https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Force.com_workbook